# Reading BLE Characteristic Arduino

Tags: swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make a drone that can be controlled with an app on an iPhone.  On the drone, I have an Adafruit Feather 32u4 BLE chip to communicate with the phone.  I have not found any way to read the data from a characteristic that the phone writes on.  The app has four buttons for forward, left, back, and right and a slider to control the throttle.  The code for the app is below:

```
import CoreBluetooth
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {


var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
var currentCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic! = nil
let txCharacteristic = CBUUID(string: "00001532-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123")

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if (peripheral.name != nil && peripheral.name! == "Drone") {
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.centralManager.connect(self.peripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey : true])
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    self.stopScan()
}

func stopScan() {
    self.centralManager.stopScan()
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    if self.peripheral != nil {
        self.peripheral.delegate = nil
        self.peripheral = nil
    }
    self.startManager()
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: peripheral.services![0])
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    print(service)
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        print(characteristic)
        let thisCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic
        if thisCharacteristic.uuid == txCharacteristic {
            self.currentCharacteristic = thisCharacteristic
            let data = throttleValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            self.peripheral.writeValue(data, for: self.currentCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
            self.label.text = "sent"
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var throttle: UISlider! {
    didSet{
        throttle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2))
        throttle.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 90, width: throttle.frame.size.width, height: throttle.frame.size.height)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var throttleLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet{
        throttleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 40, width: throttleLabel.frame.size.width, height: throttleLabel.frame.size.height)
        throttleLabel.font = throttleLabel.font.withSize(20)
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var upButton: UIButton! {
    didSet{
        upButton.frame = CGRect(x: 500, y: 50, width: upButton.frame.size.width, height: upButton.frame.size.height)
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton! {
    didSet{
        rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: 600, y: 150, width: rightButton.frame.size.width, height: rightButton.frame.size.height)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var downButton: UIButton! {
    didSet{
        downButton.frame = CGRect(x: 500, y: 250, width: downButton.frame.size.width, height: downButton.frame.size.height)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton! {
    didSet{
        leftButton.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y: 150, width: leftButton.frame.size.width, height: leftButton.frame.size.height)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.startManager()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func startManager(){
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}


var directNumber = 0
var throttleValue: String = "0"

@IBAction func goForward(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 1
}

@IBAction func stopForward1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func stopForward2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func goRight(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 2
}

@IBAction func stopRight1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func stopRight2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func goLeft(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 4
}

@IBAction func stopLeft1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func stopLeft2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func goBackward(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 3
}

@IBAction func stopBackward1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func stopBackward2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    directNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func changeThrottle(_ sender: UISlider) {
    throttleValue = String(throttle.value)
}
}
```

The code is not complete because I need to send the throttle slider data and which button is pressed.  I believe the code I have now is sending data on the characteristic because the blue light on the arduino chip blinks when I run the app.  It is usually steady when just connected.  In conclusion, I have a couple questions:

1. How do I send two different pieces of information on the same characteristic?
2. Can I send the information as integers, or do I have to convert the values to strings?
3. How do I read the characteristic on the arduino side?

Answers to any of these questions will be of great help to me.  Thank you.